# Redis in windows platform

Tags: database, node.js, redis

Can I use REDIS in my application which needs to be run in windows platform.

I'm worried about the statement in the  official [site](http://redis.io/download)

> The Redis project does not directly support Windows, however the
>   Microsoft Open Tech group develops and maintains an experimental
>   Windows port targeting Win32/64. Currently the port is not production
>   quality but can be used for development purposes on Windows
>   environments. We look forward for collaborating with the authors of
>   this efforts but currently we will not merge the Windows port to the
>   main code base.

or any other alternates(windows platform) providing the same functionality?

Comment: Same exact features? No. Perhaps you should describe which Redis features you plan to use ...

Comment: I want to use REDIS for Session storage and Socket.IO store in my Node.js app.    
Link: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Comment: Try using MongoDB instead. I believe there are adapters to connect it to express session management and socket-io.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in your understanding : Do not be confused between where your application is hosted and where Redis server is hosted.

As a separate (NoSql) Database Redis can be consumed by **MANY** client types. Check [this](http://redis.io/clients)  : you could use Redis in C#, Ruby, C, PHP, Java... So your application could be written in any technology, you *just* have to connect to a Redis server.

You're true, Redis is not directly supported on Windows but Microsoft has forked the project a few month ago. The git is available [here](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis). Even if it's not production-ready, it's a valid solution for dev environment.

The good question is : does your application could be run on multiple environnements, Windows and/or Linux ? I suppose it's a web app. This means front-end on Windows and Redis DB on Linux.

In some companies, there are strict rules in order to use only one tech : Windows or Linux. Having Cohesive technos is important, but I personally think it's sometimes better to setup everything that will help you to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, I'm developing a web app in node.js which needs to be run in windows and in a single server.